# (Solved) How to deal with Program Files (x86) as user input?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I have written this little backup script that accepts user input for the source/destination for the files. It can deal just fine with spaces and `C:\Program Files\` but can't seem to be able to deal with `C:\Program Files (x86)\`.
This is the snippet of my code that I'm using to test and resolve my issue.

```
@echo off
set sourcedef=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Source

set /P sourceinp= Location of the source [Default=%sourcedef%] : 
if "%sourceinp%" == "" ( set source=%sourcedef% ) 
if not "%sourceinp%" == "" ( set source=%sourceinp% )
echo  Source folder set as : %source% 
pause
```

If i try to give it any `Program Files (x86)` directory, the cmd.exe just closes down shop. Any tips?

**EDIT:**
Solved thanks to user "*It Wasn't Me*", huge thanks!

This is how the code looks now:

```
@echo off

set source=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Source
set /p "source= Location of the source [Default=%source%] : " string ( str ^)  
echo Source folder set as : %source%
pause
```

Comment: As per my post, It works just fine with spaces and/or C:\Program Files\. The only problem is Program Files (x86)

Comment: @John Is there anyway around this, as it's not really possible to not use Program Files (x86) and even starting the .bat file as admin doesn't resolve this

Comment: You need to escape the `(` as this has special meaning for `cmd` scripts.

Comment: @john Your comments have nothing to do with the problem described. See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bat
@echo off 

set "_source_default=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Source"

^< nul <con: set /p "_source_input= Location of the source [Default=%_source_default%] : " 

if "%_source_input%" == "" (set "_source=%_source_default%") else set "_source=%_source_input%"
   
echo\Source folder set as %_source%
%__APPDIR__%Timeout.exe /t -1 & goto=:EOF
```

---

- You can use `^< nul`, at the beginning of your line, this is a recently discovered escaping mechanical trick reported by **[@jeb](https://superuser.com/users/87731/jeb)** in **dostips.com**, that will apply to escape before user input and extended to user input:

[image]

---

- Applying/adapting this discovery to your code/input would be:

```bat
^< nul <con: can literal escaping your line and your input 
    
^< nul <con: set /p "_source_input= Location of the source [Default=%_source_default%] : "
```

---

About input this/these characters **`(`** and/or **`)`** and their escaping (if necessary)

```bat
rem :: Using only (
set /p "_input= Location : " string (  
rem ::     works ⁄⁄ output = string (  ⁄⁄  there's no need to escape

rem :: Using only )
set /p "_input= Location : " string )
rem ::     works ⁄⁄ output = string )  ⁄⁄  there's no need to escape

rem :: Using both ( and )
set /p "_input= Location : " string ( str ^)  
rem ::     works ⁄⁄ output = string ( str )  ⁄⁄  there's no need in (, only in ^)
```

- Test and outputs:

```bat
F:\2020-SU\1572099>input_testv2.cmd
Location of the source [Default=C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\Source] : string (((((((
Source folder set as :  string (((((((

F:\2020-SU\1572099>input_testv2.cmd
Location of the source [Default=C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\Source] : ))))))))))) string
Source folder set as :  ))))))))))) string

F:\2020-SU\1572099>input_testv2.cmd
Location of the source [Default=C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\Source] : ( ( ( string ^) ^) ^)
Source folder set as :  ( ( ( string ) ) )
```

- **Obs:** For each **`)`**, if you have one **`(`** previous, forming **pairs**, then yes, you will need to use each pair **`^)`**, additional **odds** **`)))`** are not necessary to escape:

```bat
F:\2020-SU\1572099>input_testv2.cmd
Location of the source [Default=C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\Source] : ( ( ( string ^) ^) ^) ))))
Source folder set as :  ( ( ( string ) ) ) ))))
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[set /?](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[Refer: `^< nul` Bug/Mystery in the phase parsing rules 1.5 and 2 CR vs redirect](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9429&start=15)**

  [√] **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**

  [√] **[Use parentheses/brackets to group expressions in a Windows batch file](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html)**

Answer (score 2):

#### If I input and `Program Files (x86)` directory, `cmd` errors

This is because `(` and `)` are special characters in `cmd` scripts and they need to be escaped using `^`.

Without escaping:

```
F:\test>test
Location of the source [Default=C:\Users\David\Desktop\Source] : C:\Program Files (x86)
) was unexpected at this time.

F:\test>
```

With escaping:

```
F:\test>test
Location of the source [Default=C:\Users\David\Desktop\Source] : C:\Program Files ^(x86^)
 Source folder set as : C:\Program Files (x86)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)
- [Parenthesis/Brackets - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html)