# Batch File: using brackets within brackets?

Tags: batch

I am having trouble with certain commands that involve brackets when they are placed within bracketed `IF` statements.

Here are two examples:

```
if condition (
title Cleanup (task 1)
) else (
title Cleanup (task 2)
)
```

and

```
if condition (
set /a var2=(100 * %var%) + 50
) else (
set /a var2=100 * (%var% + 50)
)
```

These fail and might even crash the script. Is what I am attempting here do-able? Maybe some way to force the brackets within the title and set commands to be taken literally? Or some alternative symbol that does the same job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `^` escape character for the inner parenthesis:

```
if condition ( title Cleanup ^(task 1^) ) else ( title Cleanup ^(task 2^) )
```

Comment: I did not know that trick, problem solved thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**// Edit**

Test this in your command line:

```bat
^s^e^t^ ^/^a ^y^=^0 && ^c^a^l^l ^e^c^h^o^\^%^y^%
```

And you will see all the **`^`** are completely superfluous and unnecessary but it still works, the results is the same without escaping, you can also use "double-quotes", but understand if you want to use an escaping, you only need to in **`^)`**, in your current code, and realize that the use is unnecessary in **`^(`**, it is not because it works that it makes it necessary, see more in this
**[answer](https://superuser.com/a/1572162/969781)**

- The same apply: **`set /a var2=(100 * %var%^) + 50`**

**// Edit**

---

- You only need `""` in **`set "var=(integer operator integer) operator integer"`**

```bat
@echo off 

setlocal

set "var1=1"

if x == x (
   title Cleanup (task 1^)
   ) else (
   title Cleanup (task 2^)
   )

if x == y (
   title Cleanup (task 1^)
   ) else (
   title Cleanup (task 2^)
   )

echo\ var1 == %var1% 

if not y == x (
   set /a var2=(10 * %var1%^) + 50
   ) else (
   set /a var2=10 * (%var1% + 50^)
   )

echo\ var1 == %var1% 
echo\ var2 == %var2%

if z == y (
   set /a "var2=(5 * %var1%) + 50"
   ) else (
   set /a "var2=5 * (%var1% + 50)"
   )

echo\ var1 == %var1% 
echo\ var2 == %var2%

endlocal
```

- Outputs:

```bat
 var1 == 1
 var1 == 1
 var2 == 60
 var1 == 1
 var2 == 255
```