# cmd.exe opens and immediately closes, when running a batch file(elevated mode) located in a folder which contains (

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, administrator

I am trying to execute a batch file in Windows. It is placed in a folder that contains `(` character and no space in its name.

I am executing the batch file by simply right-clicking and choosing `Run as administrator`, it opens a `cmd.exe` and then immediately closes.

**Sample location of the file:** `C:\Users\<user-name>\Downloads\Folder(1)\install.bat`

**Sample batch script:**

```
@Echo Administrative permissions required. Detecting permissions.
@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak 1> NUL
```

Any idea why it is not working?

*Note:* This question was originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242212/cmd-exe-opens-and-immediately-closes-when-running-a-batch-fileelevated-mode-l). And due to some reason, it was closed. So posting it here as it is the appropriate site to ask.

Comment: You can escape curved brackets using `^` symbol like: `folder^(1^)` but anyway the above code should work perfectly without escaping. I don't think the problem is in Brackets.

Comment: Also there was no need of reposting it here. You will more or less face the same consequences here. You should improve the question on Stack Overflow, because that's the reason it was closed.

Comment: @batchcoding____s  This is the updated revision. And it helps to reproduce the issue now. The question was closed before this revision.

Comment: @batchcoding____s do not need in 1st `(`, only in 2nd `^)`, see **[here](https://superuser.com/questions/1572099/solved-how-to-deal-with-program-files-x86-as-user-input/1572162#1572162)**

Comment: try `^)`: **`%username%\Downloads\Folder(1^)\install.bat`** or  more **safe way**, **`"%userprofile%\Downloads\Folder(1)\install.bat"`**  use **`" string "  => "something to escaping"`**

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe It's Okay. But my requirement is that running the script by right click and run as administrator.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe Tried it. no luck.

Comment: Why no add the code to your question?